# Linux Grep the delta

Tags: linux, grep

I have two files: file1, file2. I want to get the lines from file2 which don't exist in file1.

I have read a [post](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5710/intersection-between-two-files) that told me to use -v flag of grep to do it(I read the man page of grep but still did not quite get how to use -F and -x flag), but I have no luck so far.

```
$ cat file1
Eric
Cartman
Kenny
McCormick

$ cat file2
Stan
Marsh
Kyle
Broflovski
Eric
Cartman
Kenny 
McCormick

$ grep -v file1 file2
Stan
Marsh
Kyle
Broflovski
Eric
Cartman
Kenny 
McCormick
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
Stan
Marsh
Kyle
Broflovski
```

Comment: Try 'diff' (and some of its options) instead of 'grep'

Comment: The -v flag returns items that are not in both files not just the files that are in one file or another. Do you have to use grep or would a short script work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this grep line may help:

```
 grep -Fvf file1 file2
```

or with awk:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]' file1 file2
```

Comment: That works perfect for me. Can you explain the -F flag a little? in the man page, it says fixed string and interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings. Did not quite understand what it does. Seems like it still works fine for me even without the -F lag

Comment: @B.Mr.W. try `echo "abccc"|grep  'a.*c'` and `echo "abccc"|grep -F 'a.*c'` you will see

Comment: @B.Mr.W. your given example works with/without `-F` but if one line in file1 was `a.*c` and you have `abc` in file2, the `abc` line won't be printed in output. but you expect to have it there, right?

Comment: Your explanation is awesome! Without the F flag, seems like the grep might take the first argument as regular expression and something unexpected might happen if you have '$*.' all those funny characters... So it is also good to keep the F as default.